# Key Error with Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I am having some problems with key errors with my dictionary.

```
    result={}    
    for (k,v) in movies.items():
        if not v[1] in result:
            result[v[0]]=0
        result[v[0]]+=int(1)
        if not v[2] in result:
            result[v[2]]=0
        result[v[2]]+=int(1)
        if not v[3] in result:
            result[v[3]]=0
        result[v[3]]+=int(1)
        if not v[4] in result:
            result[v[4]]=0
        result[v[4]]+=int(1)
        if not v[5] in result:
            result[v[5]]=0
        result[v[5]]+=int(1)
    list5= sorted(result.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
    print list5
```

So I am trying to create a dictionary where I loop through another dictionary(movies), and add the actors in each of these movies as my keys. The keys in my dictionary are the names of the actors, and the value will be the number of movies he did in total. However I seem to be getting a key error. Any idea why that might be?

P.S- there are 5 actors in each movie, which is why I have 5 keys for the loop.

Thanks, Junaid

Comment: Please show the complete error message.

Comment: 1 is already an `int`.  `int(1)` is redundant, and it is also redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Much easier to just use a `Counter` here. As a bonus it doesn't matter anymore how many actors the movie has.

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(i for v in movies.values() for i in v)
print c.most_common()
```

Another way to loop over the actors is to use `chain.from_iterable`

```
from itertools import chain
c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(movies.values()))
print c.most_common()
```

Answer (score 1):

probably a typo somewhere here:

```
if not v[1] in result:
    result[v[0]]=0
result[v[0]]+=int(1)
```

use `defaultdict` or setdefault for simplicity, and iterate over slice for unification:

```
 import collections
 result = collections.defaultdict(int)
 for k, values in movies.items():
    for value in values[:6]: # first 6, from 0th to 5th
        result[v] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be enough for you.

```
result = {}

for movie, actor_list in movies.iteritems():
    for actor in actor_list:
        result[actor] = result.get(actor, 0) + 1

print sorted(result.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```